# Problems using \def commands inside an environment

Tags: environments, counters

In trying to build the commands `\sol` and `\solutions` to use them inside the exercises environment. The commands must work in this way:

```
\begin{exercises}
  \exer text for exercise 1\sol{solutionA}
  \exer text for exercise 2\sol{solutionB}
  \exer text for exercise 3
  \begin{subexerc}
     \sexer text for subexercise 3.a.\sol{solutionC}
     \sexer text for subexercise 3.b.\sol{solutionD}
 \end{subexerc}
\end{exercises}
```

the environments are defined here:

```
\newcounter{exercise}
\def\theexercise{\arabic{exercise}.}
\newenvironment{exercises}
  {\begin{list}{\theexercise}{} }
  {\end{list}
   Solutions\par\solutions} 
\def\exer{\refstepcounter{exercise}\item}

\newcounter{subexer}[exercise]
\def\thesubexer{\alph{subexer}.}
\newenvironment{subexerc}
  {\begin{list}{\thesubexer}{} }
  {\end{list}
\def\sexer{\refstepcounter{subexer}\item}
```

I'm tried with these definitions:

```
\def\solutions{}  

\makeatletter
\def\sol#1{%
  \ifnum\value{subexer}=0  
    \g@addto@macro\solutions{\par\noindent\theexercise\ #1}%
 \else  
    \g@addto@macro\solutions{\theexercise\thesubexer\ #1\ }%
  \fi  
}
\makeatother
```

but I'm obtained:

> ```
> 1. text for exercise 1
> 2. text for exercise 2
> 3. text for exercise 3
>       a. text for exercise 3.a
>       b. text for exercise 3.b
>
> Solutions
> 3. solutionA
> 3. solutionB3.b. solutionC 3.b. solutionD
> ```

...and I'm trying:

> ```
> 1. text for exercise 1
> 2. text for exercise 2
> 3. text for exercise 3
>       a. text for exercise 3.a
>       b. text for exercise 3.b
>
> Solutions
> 1. solutionA
> 2. solutionB
> 3.a. solutionC 3.b. solutionD
> ```

What's happening? It is like the counters `exercise` and `subexer` have always their last values!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please use code block (indented by four spaces) only and not quotation block for code. The results itself then only in quotation blocks. (Compiler messages as code blocks.) Inline code can be formatted using back-ticks `\``. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, thank you, ....how can I edit my post?

Comment: Using the 'edit' link below it. I saw now your issue with the enumeration and fixed that again.

Comment: thank you so much, ...but numeration at examples is still wrong in solutions

Comment: My apologies. This case is a little tricky. I changed it back to the original format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems that you add the macros `\theexercise` and `\thesubexer` to `\solutions`, not their values at that moment. Therefore when typeset the refer to the then current value which is the last used value of course:

```
% Wrong:
\def\sol#1{%
  \ifnum\value{subexer}=0  
    \g@addto@macro\solutions{\par\noindent\theexercise\ #1}%
 \else  
    \g@addto@macro\solutions{\theexercise\thesubexer\ #1\ }%
  \fi  
}
```

You need to expand it at that moment and add the expanded value. For this use `\edef` with a temporary macro which is then expanded using `\expandafter`s:

```
% Correct:
\def\sol#1{%
  \begingroup
  \ifnum\value{subexer}=0  
    \edef\@tempa{\noexpand\par\noexpand\noindent\theexercise}%
    \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\solutions\expandafter{\@tempa\ #1}%
  \else  
    \edef\@tempa{\theexercise\thesubexer}%
    \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\solutions\expandafter{\@tempa\ #1\ }%
  \fi
  \endgroup
}
```